# Set the table, or lay the table?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I have read that *set* is American and that *lay* is British.

But I do not think it is nearly as simple as that. I grew up in rural England in the late 1940s/50s, and we always *set* the table. In fact *lay* still jars with me now.

So who *sets* and who *lays* the table?

And in Britain, what is the social class implication? Is it posher to *set* or to *lay*. What do the servants in Downton Abbey do?

Comment: Lay the table / set the table: http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.it/2006/06/lay-table-set-table.html

Comment: @Josh61 Yes I read that before I posted and it seemed to be saying that *set* was American.

Comment: I grew up in less rural England in the 1950s, and we always _set_ the table too. And _lay_ still jars slightly with me too. We had dinner at midday.

Comment: Set the table appears to be  more common both in BrE and AmE: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+the+table+for+lunch%2Clay+the+table+for+lunch&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cset%20the%20table%20for%20lunch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clay%20the%20table%20for%20lunch%3B%2Cc0

Comment: My understanding is that they have two different meanings though they are actually synonyms: lay the table refers to lay the tablecloth, set the table means prepare the table ( for lunch/dinner). Laying the tablecloth implies a more formal/traditional context and probably for that reason the less formal 'set' is more common.

Comment: I use both forms, and I don't think my choice is affected by whether or not there's a *tablecloth* involved. But my preconceptions over "level of formality" are precisely at odds with that concept anyway.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Umm. Interesting. Once we get into what we call the different meals we really are into British society in a big way. For most British people, the pre-1950s default was clearly *breakfast, (lunch mid- morning) dinner and tea* with *supper* being a snack before bedtime. As society became more gentrified from the 1960s onward, and as work patterns changed, the main meal being taken for many in the evenings, then *lunch* and early *dinner* caught on. Calling the main evening meal *supper*, as David Cameron does, is heavily upper-middle class.

Comment: Similar point: in my experience many Americans say _set_ (and expecially _set down_) where I would say _put (down)_.

Comment: @ColinFine Interestingly that is also the case in Norfolk. In fact several Americanisms, and Australianisms,  are present in the older pre-RP way of speaking English which exists in East Anglia e.g *dawg*. Norfolk also pronounces place names like Derby and Berkshire the way Americans do.

Comment: I am American and a native AmE speaker. And I say "lay the table". Others do say set. But "set down": Set that book down on the table (yes, AmE), but Set yourself down (sit down), only in the South or rural areas.

Comment: @Lambie Yes in the rural part of England where I lived as a child (Norfolk) they say *sit (or set) you down*, or *sit yourself down*. But then they also say *take you that back to the neighbours* and use many other similar imperatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not so much *that **set** is American and that **lay** is British* - rather, that [*Brits use both forms more or less equally often...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20lay%20the%20table%2Cyou%20set%20the%20table&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20lay%20the%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20set%20the%20table%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...whereas [*Americans almost exclusively stick with **set**...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20lay%20the%20table%2Cyou%20set%20the%20table&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20lay%20the%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20set%20the%20table%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Personally, I find ***set*** slightly more "formal, dated" - but I suppose that's just because half a century ago, *my* mother always instructed one of us kids to ***lay*** the table. We were true peasants, so I always assumed ***set*** was a bit [la-di-da](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/la-di-da) (obviously it's *not*).

---

I think it's a given that since NGrams are drawn from written published sources, they'll tend to over-represent more formal usages. So I suspect that if I could compare formal/informal contexts (contracted ***I'll*** lay the table, as opposed to ***I will*** lay the table)), this might well support my gut feel about the difference (in BrE - obviously the concept is largely meaningless for AmE). But there simply aren't enough written instances to meaningfully compare.

Comment: Actually 'you set the table' is an expression that  is also used in graphic/computer context. That's why I used set/lay the table for lunch.

Comment: @Josh61: Apparently you could [set the table](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chosen+we+can+set+the+table%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) with something of that sense a century ago, but it's worth noting the writer there used "scare quotes", suggesting it was an unusual and/or new usage at the time. But it probably does account for *some* of the post-1980 increase in the charts.

Comment: What I mean is that the hits for 'you set the table'  refer also to: https://www.google.it/search?q=%22you+set+the+table%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1993,cd_max:2001&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=UPsGVeKtOMXSaKyAgvAB,  so they are not really representative of the usage in question.

Comment: @Josh61: Nothing in my answer would be undermined if I'd excluded everything from 1993 on (the date from which *your* search starts).

Comment: That is more to it if you check more recent usages. That explains the spike upward of 'you set the table' since the 80s ( technology).

Comment: @Josh61: I give up. Enlighten me. How does that affect the validity of my answer?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was interested in your comment about you being *peasants*. My own extended family, when a child, were definitely more *peasant* than *proletariat* and there was a huge difference. I always say that the biggest cultural barrier I ever had to cross was the Norwich ring road, when I first went to grammar school.

Comment: I was just pointing out the correct reading of NGram.

Comment: @WS2: My older brother went to the local grammar school, but he *hated* it. I was a dozy sod at 11 (don't recall even *taking* the 11-plus, let alone caring whether I passed or not), but by the time they invited me to transfer from the local secondary modern to the grammar I figured I'd rather stay where I was - partly "big fish in a little pond", but mainly because my brother's problems were more to do with social background than intellectual ability. My culture shock came when I started a degree course (all my fellow students seemed *very* middle-class).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The difficulties of the working-class kid breaking into the bourgeois society of the 1960s (when 25% of the population were making that shift) has been well documented. One of my own favourite authors was Dennis Potter with his *Stand-Up Nigel Barton* and *Vote, Vote, Vote for Nigel Barton*. John Osborne - *Look back in Anger* also reflects this theme. But my case was slightly different to the coal-miner's son who goes to Oxford. My folks were pig-keeping peasants and, distinctively different to Potter's characters in that they were Tory voting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But my Norfolk accent and idiom got ridiculed at grammar school.

Comment: @WS2: I don't recall any of my *peers* at uni ridiculing my accent, but it was a bit amusing in my first linguistics class when I was singled out by the lecturer as using the smallest set of phonemes he'd ever encountered in a native speaker. And when I returned home for Xmas after the first term, everyone said I'd adopted a "la-di-da" accent (before that, my ***four*** and ***full***, for example, were almost always pronounced identically, but that lecturer made me start paying a bit more attention to my diction! :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps not as humbling as discovering at age 11 that the past tense of snow is not *snew*, and that of drive not *driv*.

Comment: @WS2: I was over 40 when it was finally drummed in to me that putting stress on the *second* syllable of ***catholic*** wasn't a recognised way of distinguishing the secular "all-embracing" sense from the specific "religious sect" meaning.

Comment: The Marx Brothers joke wouldn't work with _laid_: [Officer] –'Where are the others? You can't fool me – this table's set for four!' [Groucho]–'So? My alarm clock's set for eight!'

Answer (score 2):

It is , and in my neck of the woods, London & home counties, still is,   Lay The Table.

Set the table would probably get you a slap from my Grandmother in 1953!!!

Answer (score 1):

My mother (back in England) was a true "grammar nazi" when it came to my speech. She came from a British boarding school background and she always used "lay" when it came to the table. "Diana, it's time to lay the table." I have always thought of "lay" and being British and "set" as being standard in  America (where I live now).